Is the Solana SDK V2 compatible with V1 and therefore compatible with Anchor 0.30?
I cannot find an answer on this - is Anchor 0.30 compatible with Solana-SDK V2?
Anchor version 0.30 and below seem to use Solana-SDK / solana-program dependencies 1.XX dependencies. But I cannot get V1 and V2 of the solana crates to mix when trying to compile them together.
I'm trying to create a tool that works with V2 crates - but also with V1 crates for backwards compatibility reasons but not clear if it's possible

In my experience, Anchor 0.30 is compatible with solana SDK V2. but mixing v1 and v2 crates within the same project can lead to complications.
in other words, integrating both SDK V1 and V2 in one project happen some challenge.
This is due to potential conflicts and differences between the two versions, which may cause compilation issues.
So I suggest you to use any one version in one project.

Anchor-lang https://crates.io/crates/anchor-lang/0.30.1/dependencies is compatible here with ^1.17 (< 2)
